# Django refresh page handler

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

i've created a page with Django. views.py executes a request that loads json file and transfers data retrieved to my template.
Everything works fine, but i wonder how to handle the action of refreshing the page, because every time a user does this, views.py will execute the request again and that may cause a lot of problems and timeouts.

I think there might be two alternatives. 
First one is to store variables passed to my template and do some of javascript. Second one, handling views.py and asking if json variable is not empty

Comment: also you can use a cookies

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand how to perform this. What's your idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think django cache should work : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I've managed with the following:

The Per-View Cache

Comment: The per-view cache is great when you don't need to invalidate caches. Sometimes when you need to invalidate them, a django extension helps it. https://ring-cache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ring/django.html#ring.django.cache_page